# I have an Excel Spreadsheet where I'd like to compare columns B through D with F through H and highlight matches

Tags: excel-2013

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 2 named tables of columns: B, C and D (Table1), and F, G and H (Table2).

I want to find the rows in Table1 that are in Table2, in Column J, I entered this formula ...

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Table1[[$B]:[$D]],Table2,1,FALSE)),"Not in Table 2","In Table 2")
```

All cells returned the "In Table 2" value.

I want to find the rows in Table1 that are in Table2, in Column K, I entered this formula ...

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Table2[[$F]:[$H]],Table1,1,FALSE)),"Not in Table 1","In Table 1")
```

All cells returned the "In Table 1" value.   ;-)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I dont understand the purpose of dollar sign in this formulas, as far as i know it's fixed reference and it means that if you copy formula to next row it will not be adjusted, so probably all cells are trying to find first row in table1 and table2. And i don't think vlookup can search for row, it can only search for value.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you replace `[$F]:[$H]` with column names in @ notation (assuming you have key column). `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Table1[@x],Table2,1,FALSE)),"Not in Table 2","In Table 2")` and `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Table2[@o],Table1,1,FALSE)),"Not in Table 1","In Table 1")` (Sorry, I have localized excel)
[image: excel]

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to string the row components together for comparison purposes, say with in J2:

```
=B2&"|"&C2&"|"&D2
```

and in K2:

```
=F2&"|"&G2&"|"&H2
```

both copied down to suit. Then apply Conditional Formatting, for example select ColumnsB:D and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=MATCH($B1&"|"&$C1&"|"&$D1,$K:$K,0)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select highlighting of choice, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.